# concat not beeing recognized by mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-query

I have this field on my collection:

```
uniqueId: 123
inTarefa: true
exclude: "ab,cd,"
orderId: 987
```

and I'm trying to update all values using a "FindOneAndUpdate" like this:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({
'uniqueId': 123
},
{{
  "$set":{
  "inTarefa":false,
  "orderId":0,
  "exclude":{"$concat":["$exclude","servico"]}
}}})
```

inTarefa and orderId is successfully changed but the "exclude" is changed to an object like this:

```
exclude:{$concat:[0: "$exclude", 1: "servico"]}
```

Yeah, this is exactly what it's supposed to do IF the keyword "$concat" was not a command to mongodb. What I'm doing wrong?

Mongodb version: 4.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$concat` is an aggregation operator, you should use the pipelined form of update. Try this:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({
'uniqueId': 123
},
[
  {"$set":{
    "inTarefa":false,
    "orderId":0,
    "exclude":{"$concat":["$exclude","servico"]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: I can't do this, when I try to put "$set" inside of an [] I get an error. Are you sure the right way is not something like [{$set: ...}]?

Comment: Yess, you are right, that was a mistake from my end